# Codeception tests fail with cleanup

Tags: php, unit-testing, phalcon, codeception

I have unit tests, that add records to database, my assertions looks like:

```
...
$this->upService->addActivity($activity, $participation, $competition); //adding records
$this->tester->seeInDatabase('table', ['value' => 2000]);
$this->tester->seeInDatabase('table2', ['saldo' => '10.101']);
}
```

I have configured Db module, Phalcon2 module and sql dump. Test passes with configuration:

```
populate: false
cleanup: false
```

But there stay test records in databse, so I use:

```
populate: false
cleanup: true
```

But in this case, test fails and database stay clear. Hot to fix it?

Comment: How does your test fail? Please provide more information.

Comment: Isn't that what cleanup's supposed to do, keep the database clear? How are you deciding if the test failed or not? Can you show us your full codeception.yml file (starring out sensitive info of course)? Are you getting any errors in your error log? Are you logging errors?

Comment: If you could put your complete Codeception .yml configuration (basically the modules part), it would be great!